# Syntax to initialize array functionally in C#, similar to python

Tags: c#, python, functional-programming

Python offers the following syntax to initialize a python List functionally:

```
mylist = [item for item in iterable]
```

Is there a similar syntax in C# for initializing a C# List?

EDIT:

I guess I should be more specific. I'm trying to emulate the following syntax:

```
mylist = [operation(item) for item in iterable]
```

Comment: [List<T> Constructor (IEnumerable<T>)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0.aspx)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `iterable` is an `IEnumerable<T>` of some sort, you can use the [`List<T>(IEnumerable<T>)` constructor overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to initialize a new list:

```
mylist = new List(iterable);
```

You can also call the Linq [`Enumberable.ToList` extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb342261%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
mylist = iterable.ToList();
```

---

Specifically, it looks like you're after how to do the equivalent of list comprehension. You can use [Linq's `Enumerable.Select` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and a lambda. For example, to match your edit:

```
mylist = iterable.Select(item => operation(item)).ToList();
```

---

As a bonus, if you were trying to do the following (adding a condition):

```
mylist = [operation(item) for item in iterable if item > 42]
```

You would add a call to [`Enumerable.Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549418%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in the chain:

```
mylist = iterable.Where(item => item > 42).Select(item => operation(item)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You may create a C# List of items, say ints, in the following manor:

```
List<int> myList = new List<int>{1, 2, 3, 4,};
```

So you don't need to specify the initial size, it infers it from your initial objects. If you instead have an enumerable, see the code below

```
IEnumerable<int> existingEnumerable = ...
List<int> myList = new List<int>(existingEnumerable);
```

Let us know if this fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you just turn an iterable collection into an array.

In C#, there is a `.ToArray()` extension method on a collection type. Maybe that is what you need.

It would be:

```
result=iterable.ToArray();
```

---

after the edit, it appears you are to transform list.

```
myList=iterable.Select(i=> Operation(i));
```

Comment: Sorry, I edited my post. But your answer is right, for my original question.